# How relevant are regularity, uniqueness and such "mathematical" concepts for engineering applications?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How relevant are regularity, uniqueness and such "mathematical" concepts for engineering applications?

Possibly they're required for computation of the equations, no?

Comment: Usually where the conditions for these theorems, like continuous right sides or a moderate, relatively global Lipschitz constant in the Lipschitz condition, are violated, you get in the numerical solution a stiff DE or something that has solutions stopping in the middle of the domain with no possible continuation.

Comment: Just as an example, I once had a summer sabbatical with NASA engineers working on automatic docking in Earth orbit. I pointed out that there was no guarantee that a particular equation had a unique solution, and that, in fact it had two solutions. Luckily they were using the correct solution rather than the 'solution' which would have led to a collision.